# \DeclareNameAlias not working as expected

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to reverse the order of the first and last names, and also use first initials. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
  @Article{ref1,
    author    = {Nye, Bill and Bean, Mister},
    title     = {{Intergalactic car parking}},
    journal   = {PLoS Parking},
    year      = {2017}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: `authoryear` uses `sortname` for the alias.

Changing:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
```

to

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

gives the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

There is no name format `last-firstinits`. You would get the same output if you would use `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{blub}`.

Use the option giveninits along with `family-given`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2, backend=biber,giveninits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\begin{document}
  A\footcite{wilde}
  B\footcite{cicero}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: True. This works. However, my original problem came from a different MWE, which does not follow this behavior. I've updated the question. Sorry for the bad forum form.

Comment: You are not changing sortname.